# How to remove countings from a cell in Excel (linux)

Tags: linux, excel, command, numerics

I have a data in Excel with the following format:

```
0 PLEKHG6   0 ZIC1     0 YOD1      0 PLEKHG6    0 DCUN1D1   0 CAMK2N1
1 SKIL      1 MOB4     1 HOXB1     1 SKIL       1 KLF3      1 DLX5
2 YOD1      2 DGKI     2 FIGN      2 YOD1       2 GRM7      2 WDR26
3 FIGN      3 SKIL     3 FIGN      3 POU2F1     3 COL12A1
4 BCAT1     4 CPEB1    4 COIL      4 KAT6B      4 VTI1A
5 COIL      5          5 HOXB1     5 HCN1       5 SIX1
6 HOXB1     6          6 CPEB1     6 SRRM2  
7 CPEB1                7 ULK3      7 CNKSR2
```

and I want an output without counting in each column like as following:

```
PLEKHG6     ZIC1       YOD1    PLEKHG6  DCUN1D1    CAMK2N1   
SKIL        MOB4       HOXB1   SKIL     KLF3       DLX5
YOD1        DGKI       FIGN    YOD1     GRM7       WDR26 
FIGN        SKIL       FIGN    POU2F1   COL12A1
BCAT1       CPEB1      COIL    KAT6B    VTI1A
COIL                   HOXB1   HCN1     SIX1
HOXB1                  CPEB1   SRRM2    
CPEB1                  ULK3    CNKSR2
```

Using Excel in Linux how can I do that??? Just to emphasize that some the data length in each column is not same. Some of them have empty spaces and some have just numbers.

Comment: You'll have to clarify this question.  You can't use Excel in Linux.  What tool will you be using to manipulate the Excel file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

The above has workable solution. Not mine.